# jquery selectors - All rows of a table except the last 3 records

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How to select all rows of a table **except** the last 3 of them with jQuery selectors?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the [`:lt`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector with a negative value:

```
$("#tableId tr:lt(-3)")
```

As noted by @squint, this method is not optimal in terms of performance. For better performance, use @Vega's answer.

From the [`:lt`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) documentation:

> Because `:lt()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using `:lt()` cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()`
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   `$("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0, index)` instead.

Comment: @andcl85: This works, but I'd do the `.slice()` for selection efficiency. The `:lt(-3)` is a non-standard jQuery invention so it isn't optimized and isn't useful outside jQuery.

Comment: @squint Thanks for the insight squint! I didn't know that. I tried to add it to the answer appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

As [@Lye Fisk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3352025/lye-fish) pointed out, You need the start index to get all rows except last 3

```
$('#yourtable tr').slice(0, -3) //should return all rows except last 3
```

You could use jQuery [slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) with a negative number to pop the end elements.

```
$('#yourtable tr').slice(-3) //should return the last 3
```

Comment: Thanks, Vega. But that code only selects the last 3 records... I need every record **except** the last 3 of them...

Comment: @andcl85: `.slice(0, -3)` Be sure to follow the link in the answer and read the docs so you understand how it works.